# Using components from PCA as index / measurement?

Tags: pca, cross-validation, scales, validation

I have used Principal Component Analysis to find main components that desribe the perceptions of the environment. The goal is to use those main components as index / measurement for another study. My problem is if I find a "parsimonious description of the variables" and use that as an index for the next study, how can I be sure that people what that term actually means (which variables it included)?

So, I found that e.g. pleasant, comfortable, relaxing, welcoming etc. to be in the same component and decide to call them "positive perception" as use it in the next study as "How do you find those environments in terms of "positive perception"? How are people going to know that "positive perception" means pleasant, comfortable, relaxing and welcoming?

Do I need another validation study to confirm that the new term I came up with is appropriately describing the variables? Would it be enough to ask a number of people what word they think would describe those variables best? Or what they think "positive perception" means?

Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you performed PCA on scores derived from a validated survey. In your PCA, respondents’ scores for the terms "pleasant", "comfortable", "relaxing", and "welcoming" are highly correlated with a single PC, which you have called "positive perception".  Now, you want to be able to ask fewer questions (shorter survey, less time-consuming for respondents).

I am afraid you would indeed have to perform a validation study to ensure “positive perception” was a good replacement for all those other terms.  I am also afraid “positive perception” would make a poor replacement:  “pleasant”, “relaxing”, etc are much easier to relate to, and this is very important in a survey.

If you want to reduce the number of questions in your survey, look at the correlation between, say, a respondent’s scores for “pleasant”, “comfortable”, etc.  If these are highly correlated with one another, you could keep only one of them and drop the others.